# Scikit-learn - user-defined weights function for KNeighborsClassifier

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I have a KNeighborsClassifier which classifies data based on 4 attributes. I'd like to weight those 4 attributes manually but always run into "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,5) (4)".

There is very little documentation on `weights : [callable] : a user-defined function which accepts an array of distances, and returns an array of the same shape containing the weights.`(from [here](http://amueller.github.io/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html))

This is what I have for now :

```
    for v in result:
        params = [v['a_one'], v['a_two'], v['a_three'], v['a_four']]
        self.training_data['data'].append(params)
        self.training_data['target'].append(v['answer'])

    def get_weights(array_weights):
        return [1,1,2,1]

    classifier = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(weights=get_weights)
```

Comment: the link is not really to the main page. Did you find that via google? I should probably take it down, then. The weights are for rescaling the distances, I think. I you want to rescale the features, why not just rescale them in the input space?

Comment: yes, found via google - the documentation seems a bit all over the place. Which page should I be looking at, rather?

Comment: [scikit-learn.org](http://scikit-learn.org).

Answer (score 6):

Explanation of the sklearn weights callable

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
```

Create sample data for model training

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'feature1':[1,3,3,4,5], 'response':[1,1,1,2,2]})

y = df.response
# [1,1,1,2,2]

X_train = df[['feature1']]
# [1,3,3,4,5]
```

Define a custom distance function (print input data structure)

```
def my_distance(weights):
    print(weights)
    return weights
```

Define model passing in my_distance as a callable to weights

```
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3, weights=my_distance)

knn.fit(X_train,y)

knn.predict([[1]])
# [[ 0.  2.  2.]]
# array([1])
```

Explanation: display the 3 closest neighbors (n_neighbors=3) to the predicted value of 1

The three closest neighbors to 1 in X_train:

```
1, 3, 3
```

The distances:

```
[[ 0.  2.  2.]]

1 - 1 = 0 
3 - 1 = 2
3 - 1 = 2
```

The predicted class:

```
array([1])
```

Comment: Could You provide an example using the Gaussian function, with sigma as a parameter, please? =)

Comment: In this nice example the targets of the farest neighbors have the highest impact (i guess it is unreasonable in most cases). still good example to see how it works. thanks @Alex

Answer (score 0):

For Gaussian
##gamma is a hyperparameter here - we need to select the best fit.

```
def gaussian_kernel(distance):
     weights = np.exp(-gamma*(distance**2))
     return weights/np.sum(weights)
```

Comment: Your answer is not very clear. How does it solve the question?

Comment: I think its a response to the comment below the other answer. @Nostradamnit