# Applying user defined weights in KNeighbourClassifier in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

can any one please guide me in writing a user-defined function to provide weights for KNeighborClassifier in python(sklearn)?   If possible please explain with an example

Comment: did you try to follow the description from the docs: [callable] : a user-defined function which accepts an array of distances, and returns an array of the same shape containing the weights? Does it work, or do you get any errors? Provide example of your code

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327880/scikit-learn-user-defined-weights-function-for-kneighborsclassifier